# Laravel fire event из скрипта

Tags: php, laravel, события

Настроен apache 2 сервер на линуксе и установлен laravel 5.2, есть php скрипт который слушает сокет, можно ли из этого скрипта вызвать Event::fire для laravel?

Comment: @totorro частое мелькание курсива и обычного текста только ухудшает читаемость, честно

Comment: @Etki мне наоборот лучше когда основные "игровые" персонажи как то выделены. Я сначла пробегаюсь взглядом по ним - понимаю что смогу ответить и тогда вчитываюсь в вопрос. Но ок, посыл понял.

Comment: @totorro для этого существуют метки

Comment: @totorro: соглашусь с Etki. Гораздо лучше будет поставить правильные метки (если их ещё нет). Про курсив подробнее тут: [Когда стоит использовать внутристрочное выделение для кода?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1338)

Answer (score 1):

в роуты добавил обработку пост запроса

`Route::post('/zb', 'ZBController@post');`

с помощью curl из скрипта отправляю данные

```
$url = 'http://localhost/zb';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  http_build_query($zmsg, '', '&'));
$out = curl_exec($ch);
echo $out;
curl_close($ch);
```

$zmsg - это объект который я заполняю в скрипте
подробнее можно посмотреть в мануалах по curl

В контроллере получаю данные и вызываю событие

```
public function post(Request $request)
{
    event(new ZbMsgRecieved($request->all()));

}
```